# Complex definition in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Because I have been confused, Can someone explain me what `*(int*)a`  or `*(int*)b` is in the following example, type casting or some complex pointer declaration? I need to use bsearch function. Thanks

```
int cmpfunc(const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}
```

Comment: It's casting a `void *` to an `int *` then dereferencing it to access the `int` it points to.  Presumably it's known that these `void *` arguments point to `int`s.

Comment: You can't have a declaration in the middle of an expression. `(int *)` casts to pointer-to-int; `*` in front of that dereferences the pointer.

Comment: As a side note, using subtraction to check which `int` is larger isn't reliable unless you can be sure the subtraction won't overflow/underflow.

Comment: Your compiler should cry out loud for casting away the `const` qualifier. Presuming the pointer are indeed `int *`, the cast should be `const int *`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a cast.  `a`, which is of type `const void *`, is first cast to an `int *`, then that `int *` is dereferenced to read an `int`.

Breaking it down:

- `a`: type `const void *`
- `(int *)a`: type `int *`
- `*(int *)a`: type `int`.

The reason this is done is because a function of type `int (*)(const void *, const void *)` is required to be passed to the `bsearch` and `qsort` functions as a callback.  Defining the arguments as `const void *` allows `qsort` to sort any arbitrary data by having the callback function cast the arguments to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

A more readable version without explicit (and potentially unsafe) casts would be

```
int cmpfunc(const void * a_, const void * b_)
{
    int const *a = a_;
    int const *b = b_;

    return *a - *b;
}
```